# React native custom view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I am developing an app where the user adds item name, description, quantity and image url and it gets stored in `AsyncStorage`. I have made it ready and it looks like this:

[image]

Now i am trying to fetch it from `Asyncstorage` and i Get a 2D array. Here is the code:

```
myA1 = await AsyncStorage.getItem('key1');
   var ee=JSON.parse(myA1); //ee is 2D array
```

It looks like this

```
[[imgurl1 itemname1, desc1, quantity1],
 [imgurl2 itemname2, desc2, quantity3],
 [imgurl3 itemname3, desc2, quantity3],
 [imgurl4 itemname4, desc2, quantity3]]
```

How can I acheive this??
I am beginner for react native

I want to display it as follows

[image]:

Comment: is your question is how to render your data like your picture? i mean, how to show data in a list?

Comment: @AliSn yes sir.

Answer (score 1):

You van use `FlatList` for rendering a list of data. It has a `renderItem` prop that you can pass a view to render each row of data like that. Put your data in an state (`data` in this code). Here is an example:

```
makeContentItem(item) {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    //Do sth when clicking on a row
            }}>
                <View style={{ width: '90%', height: 140, marginBottom: 5, borderRadius: 2, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        <Image style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }} source={require(item.imgurl)} />
                        <View>
                            <Text>{item.itemname}</Text>
                            <Text>{item.desc}</Text>
                            <Text>{item.quantity}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
     );
}


render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                return this.makeContentItem(item) 
            }
        />
    )
}
```

You can change the style to achieve what you want. also you can take a look at [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)

I hope it will help

Comment: The solution doesn't display blank views. no text or image gets displayed

Comment: It's not an accurate source. You can use FlatList to display an array of data objects and you can define the view of each row by renderItem prop. it gives you the current rendering item and you can make your appearance. for example your item may has imgurl, itemname, desc and quantity. foe more simplest example you can first read and test the react native documentation examples about flatlist in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html .

Answer (score 0):

```
renderEditAndClose() {
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "flex-end"}}>
        {this.renderEditImage()}
        {this.renderCloseImage()}
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderImageAndItemData(item: Object) {
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:"row"}}>
        {this.renderItemImage()}
        {this.renderItemData(item)}
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderItemImage(width: number, height: number, url: string) {
    return (
      <Image style={{ width: width, height: height }} source={{uri: url}} />
    );
  }
  renderItemData(item: Object) {
    return(
      <View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-around"}}>
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
          <Text>{item.quantity}</Text>
        </View>
        <Text>{item.description}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderRow(item: Object) {
    return() {
        <View>
          {this.renderEditAndClose()}
          {this.renderImageAndItemData(item)}
        </View>
    }
  }
  render() {
      return (
        <FlatList data={ee}
                  renderItem={(item) => this.renderRow(item)} />
      );
  }
```

Comment: It would be good to provide some explanatory notes with your code for people to search or understand better what you are doing.